# REElocate: Fatal error: Call to undefined function ee()

Tags: add-on

Good Afternoon,

I'm trying to install the REElocate module. I see it in the Control Panel, but when I click *Install*, I get the following error:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function ee() in [omitted]/expressionengine/third_party/reelocate/upd.reelocate.php on line 39

upd.reelocate.php line 39:

```
ee()->db->insert('modules', array(
```

Line 39 context:

```
public function install()
{   
    // register module
    ee()->db->insert('modules', array(
        'module_name' => 'Reelocate',
        'module_version' => $this->version,
        'has_cp_backend' => 'y',
        'has_publish_fields' => 'n'));
    
    return true;
}
```

I'm running v2.1.3 build 20101220.

The docs at https://github.com/expressodev/reelocate state:

> Requirements
>
> ExpressionEngine 2.1.3+

Many thanks,
Andrea

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Derek is right, the docs were out of date. The latest version of Reelocate now requires EE 2.6 (this has now been corrected in the README).

If you need to use Reelocate with an older version of ExpressionEngine, you can download older versions here:

https://github.com/expressodev/reelocate/releases

Answer (score 3):

If an add-on is calling `ee()`, it requires 2.6+. My guess is that Adrian never got around to updating the docs.

Comment: Am I correct to assume that $this->EE->db->insert() would work with EE 2.1.3?

Comment: I took a closer look at the GitHub repo and noticed that older versions of the add-on are available & use the $this->EE->db->insert() function. I'll give one of those a shot. Thanks!